# How to display two cards horizontally with equal height using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Im using bootstrap. Need to place two cards of equal row-height. Each card is placed inside col-xs-6. Card contains text and buttons. When i use `col-height col-xs-6 card` both the card join together. Could be please help me on this.

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="row-height">
        <div class="col-height col-middle col-xs-6 card">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
              <h3 class="heading-s1">Login</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn big-btn no-border red-background unstyle-anchor" style="padding: 13px 50px;">Login!</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-height col-middle col-xs-6 card">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
              <h3 class="heading-s1">Sign UP</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn big-btn no-border red-background unstyle-anchor" style="padding: 13px 50px;">Sign Up!</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: https://scotch.io/bar-talk/different-tricks-on-how-to-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height

Comment: @SankarRaj Please have a look on it.

Comment: @LaljiTadhani That is for a single card. My requirement is for two cards of equal height palced horizontally. Here the problem is, not getting space between cards

Comment: What do you meant by _card join together_? do you want padding  between two cards?

Comment: @SankarRaj yes. You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that you want?

`.row` should be wrapped into `.container`

```css
.card {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-height">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-height col-middle col-xs-5 pull-left card">
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
          <h3 class="heading-s1">Login</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn big-btn no-border red-background unstyle-anchor" style="padding: 13px 50px;">Login!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-height col-middle col-xs-5 pull-right card">
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
          <h3 class="heading-s1">Sign UP</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn big-btn no-border red-background unstyle-anchor" style="padding: 13px 50px;">Sign Up!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```